# How to draw a line that passes through a point of y-axis with a slope -3?

Tags: r, plot, addition

I have drawn a figure where I need to add a straight line such that that line passes through a point of y-axis (say y2) with a particular slope (m)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `abline`, here a line with intercept 80.06 and slope=-3, because you example is not visible.

```
plot(x, y)
abline(a=80.06, b=-3)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
y <- c(83, 62, 73, 73, 60, 51, 63, 49)
x <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)
```

Comment: @LyT Welcome. Don't be confused that the line doesn't visibly cut the y axis at 80.06, because x axis starts later than zero. You can change that by doing `plot(x, y, xlim=c(0, max(x)), xaxs='i')`.